# What's a good framework to get started developing mobile apps as a symfony2 developer

Tags: php, android, ios, symfony, web-applications

I need to create mobile applications based on developed symfony2 projects, 
I have a few applications which are already developed with symfony2 and since I don't want to get started from scratch, the idea is to have the current controllers of the apps return json data, which are used by the mobile apps as a data source for the mobile app framework.

I'm struggling to find a good starting point.

Comment: Have you looked at PhoneGap?

Comment: Ionic would be the way to go. Have in mind, however, that the path to get your Ionic/PhoneGap/Cordova app published in iOS App Store is long and painful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **ionic** to do a layout and and api rest to load data with symfony2 (for example)

Ionic is a html, javascript framework to do apps

http://ionicframework.com/

or others like ionic ( http://phonegap.com/ , http://goratchet.com/, Titanium, etc)